# import xml data into mysql, how to manage modifications to the file

Tags: php, mysql, xml, import

I'll be importing data from another website into my db, the external data I'll be reading before importing into my database is xml.

I'll be running the script every 15 minutes to check the xml file.

What is the best way to go about inserting/modifying/deleting data?

I know I can just delete all the data from the database table before the importing the data from the xml but there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You could create a transformation with an ETL-Tool like Pentaho Kettle, which does the desired import. It should be easily possible to check if something has changed, and do nothing if not necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing in XML as opposed to processing and storing the data itself? and do you need to store a history of modifications?

Comment: @nickhar I am reading the xml file from the third party website, then storing it into my db, I'm not storing the xml file as is in the table.

Comment: Do you have to update the data stored in database?

Comment: @luchosrock no not necessarily, I am looking for the best way to handle the xml import every 15 mins with inserting/deleting/updating data

Comment: so the question refers to the best way in php to parse the xml document and prepare the insert/update/delete script ?

Comment: No, just in theory the best way handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the Truncate keyword in your statement?

```
TRUNCATE TableName;INSERT INTO....
```

regards